# How can I keep an image from breaking out of my body container?

Tags: html, css

When I insert an img into the article element it makes it so my body no longer is 100% of the browser height.

Without the image the body scales fine, goes all the way down to the bottom of the screen. But upon adding the image, it does not push the body background down. What am I doing wrong? If more info is needed let me know.

[Picture of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3sVi.png)

```css
html {
  background: #7f4160;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
  background: #424160;
  color: #000;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 800px;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  padding: 2em 2em 4em;
  border-left: 3px solid #573444;
  border-right: 3px solid #573444;
}

main {
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #424160;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #222;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-size: 100px;
  color: #c66d99;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: .5px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #7f4160;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 1.3em;
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: 600;
}

img {
  background: transparent;
  border: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 95%;
}


/*  Navigation */

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #7f4160;
  text-align: center;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
}

nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #c66d99;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<header>
  <h1> Dealated</h1>
</header>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="design.html">Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="writing.html">Writing</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<main>
  <article>
    <img src="images/me.jpg" align="right">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    This website is a work in progress. Sorry for the mess!
    <br>-Jessica
  </article>
</main>
<footer>
  All content is &copy; Jessica Griffin as of 2023.
</footer>
```

Comment: You should put all your code here, and most important, what are you expecting?

Comment: Edited it to add the full code. I am expecting my body element (the purple area) to go completely down to the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to apply a "clearfix" solution to the  element to ensure that it properly contains its floated child elements.
"clearfix" is a technique used in CSS to ensure that an element properly contains its floated child elements. When an element contains floated elements, it can sometimes collapse and not extend to the full height of its floated contents.

You can read more [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).

Here's an example of how you can modify your code:

```
<body>
  <main>
    <article class="clearfix">
      <img src="https://www.lawrenceprospera.org/images/quintana/Page_Under_Construction.jpg" width="600px" align="right">
      <h2>Hello</h2>
      This website is a work in progress. Sorry for the mess!
    </article>
  </main>
</body>
```

And you can add the following CSS code to create the clearfix:

```
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Side note:
Please consider using CSS classes instead of inline styles (align="right", width="600px") for better separation of concerns and maintainability.

Comment: This smells like chat GPT

Comment: The information originates from my cortex, while the grammatical abilities are thanks to ChatGPT.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the reason the picture was breaking out was the way I had positioned the body element. I changed it so that the body element is now positioned absolutely, and the elements inside of it are no longer "breaking out" of it.

```html
body {
    background: #def2ff;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-width: 800px;
    min-height: 100%;
    border-left: 4px solid #dbc2ff;
    border-right: 4px solid #dbc2ff;
    position:absolute;
}
```